# How to get the property value in the installshield 2019 which is set by c++ dll SetMsiProperty api?

Tags: c++, installshield, custom-action

I am using installshield 2019 professional.
I want to validate username/password provided by user. I have written a custom action in c++ dll and from that setting a property using SetMsiProperty method. 
Now, I am trying to use that property value in the condition to spawn dialogue. But in the installer I could not able to get the property.
Is that the same way to do that? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is bad form to take a password and store it in a property at runtime. If you log your install and then search for that property, or password value, you see it right there in the log plain as day. Bad security!

To actually answer your question is fairly easy especially if you have any experience with .Net. Since you're using SetMsiProperty can you guess the answer? Try looking for GetMsiProperty.

Sometimes MS changes it up to [MsiGetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msigetpropertya)

Comment: I am using c++ dll code it is validating the username/password and trying to set result "true"/"false" as a msi property VALID_USER_PASS. There I have used SetMsiProperty but again in the installshield, it is unable to get that VALID_USER_PASS property value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you're getting the property are you able to see what it is retrieving for a string?

Comment: 1. Written a custom action in c++ dll
2. This custom action get username, domain and password from the property.
3. Validate using LogonUser API and return the bool result true/false.
4. Now on the basis of that result I am trying to set msi property using SetMsiProperty method. Setting property VALIDUSERNAMEPASSWORD to "true" or "false".
5. In the next button behavior added a condition, if VALIDUSERNAMEPASSWORD = "true" it will go to next page else it will spwan error dialogue.
So here I am not getting VALIDUSER....  property value in the installshiled.